# What happens if you read from an unloaded MappedByteBuffer?

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

What happens if you read/write into [MappedByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) that is unloaded?

Will the operation fail? Will it read/write the underlying file more slowly than it would if the file was memory-mapped? Will it trigger a `load()` followed by the read/write?

The specification does not seem to indicate one way or another, but at the same time it doesn't indicate that `get()` and `put()` may throw an exception for this case so I'm not sure what to expect.

I would prefer an answer driven by the specification as opposed to peeking at the underlying source-code that may change in the future.

Comment: "... if the file was memory-mapped?": it *is* memory-mapped, and that persists until GC. See the Javadoc. It isn't *loaded* into memory if `isLoaded()` returns `false`. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Re-reading the specification, [isLoaded()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html#isLoaded()) does not indicate whether the file was "unmapped" but rather that the memory-map might have been swapped out.

So, assuming I understand this correctly, any subsequent reads/writes will trigger page faults which will reload the map into physical memory.